# chaining database queries using promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, callback, promise

I'm trying to use the `spread` method to accumulate promised results that I've read in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849312/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-resolved-promise-values-down-to-a-final-then-chai) with `Q.js`. It works in another block of code but not in the following `app.get` example. I want to chain queries using `Sequelize` and `mongoose` and pass all the returned data to the spread method. Here's my attempt:

```
var db = require('./db/managedb'); // Sequelize
var mongo_models = require('./db/mongo_model')(mongoose);
var WB = mongo_models.Webdata,
Est = mongo_models.Estimate;

app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){ 
   var filename = req.param("tagId");
   var mysql = db.db.query('CALL procedure()').then(function(rows) {
      console.log(rows);
   });  // Sequelize

   var nosql = WB.find().exec(function(err,k){
      console.log(k);
   }) // Mongoose

   var nosql2 = Est.find().exec(function(err,la){
      console.log(la);
   }) // Mongoose

   Q.try(function(){
       return mysql
    }).then(function(mysqls){
       return [ mysqls,nosql]
    }).then(function(mysqls,nosqls){
       return [mysqls,nosqls,nosql2]
    }).spread(function(mysqls,nosqls,nosql2s){
       res.render(filename+'.html', {my:mysqls,wb:nosqls,est:nosql2s}) 
    }).catch(function(error){ 
       console.log('fail')   
   })
})
```

I'm just getting a blank page with `Cannot GET /p/5` and there's no "fail" shown in the console.log. Here's my original code that works, but it's suffering from callback hell.

```
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){ 
   var filename = req.param("tagId");
   db.db.query('CALL procedure()').then(function(rows) {
     WB.find().exec(function(err,wb){
       Est.find().exec(function(err,est){
         res.render(filename+'.html', {my:rows,wb:wb,est:est}) 
       }) 
     })
  }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log('own: database error');
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using them as proxies:

```
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){ 
   var filename = req.param("tagId");
   var rows = db.db.query('CALL procedure()');
   var wb = WB.find().exec();
   var est = Est.find().exec();
   Promise.props({my: rows, wb: wb, est: est}).then(function(obj){
       res.render(filename+'.html', obj) 
   }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log('own: database error'); // not sure I'd just supress it
   });
});
```

Bluebird is already available through sequelize if you don't have it in your project.

Alternatively, you don't have to put them in specific variables:

```
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){ 
   var filename = req.param("tagId");
   Promise.props({
       my:  db.db.query('CALL procedure()'), 
       wb: WB.find().exec(), 
       est: Est.find().exec()
   }).then(function(obj){
       res.render(filename+'.html', obj); 
   }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log('own: database error'); // not sure I'd just supress it
   });
});
```